# Object throws NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, list, object, nullreferenceexception

- I have a class `Product` containing few public `properties`
- I have another class `ListOfProducts` that should contain a List of `Product` objects
- I have a method in my service.svn class where I'm retrieving rows and want to add `Product` objects into the List present in class `ListOfProducts` by creating an object of ListOfProducts and return this object. 
  But seems like Its not the way it should be done. Because the `service_GetObjectCompleted` that receives this List throws `NullReferenceException`.

`ListOfProducts` class

```
[DataContract()]
public class ListOfProducts
{
    [DataMember()]
    public List<Product> ProductList { get; set; }

    public ListOfProducts()
    {
        ProductList = new List<Product>();
    }
}
```

The method in Service.svn class that creates an object `ListOfProducts` and add `Product` objects to its List

```
public ListOfProducts GetObject()
{
    ListOfProducts Listproducts = new ListOfProducts();
    ........
    using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Product product = new Product(reader["Name"].ToString(), reader["Code"].ToString());
            Listproducts.ProductList.Add(product);
        }
    }
    return Listproducts;
}
```

WCF's Completed Event which receives `Listproducts` in `e` returned from the above method:

```
void service_GetObjectCompleted(object sender, GetObjectCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.Count != 0)  //throws NullReferenceException
    {
        PagedCollectionView pagingCollection = new PagedCollectionView(e.Result);
        pgrProductGrids.Source = pagingCollection;
        grdProductGrid.ItemsSource = pagingCollection;
    }
}
```

I think my concept is wrong over here. Is it the right way to create Object of List?

**EDIT**

In the Page's Constructor, this is how I am subscribing the `GetObjectCompleted` event

```
service.GetObjectCompleted += service_GetObjectCompleted;
```

On a button click event I am calling `GetObject` Asynchronously

```
service.GetObjectAsync();
```

Comment: at what point you are getting this exception. ?

Comment: In `service_GetObjectCompleted` wherever I have referenced `e` which means its `null`. Despite returning an object from `GetObject` its null. What am I doing wrong? Is it the correct way to send an object that creates List of other class?

Comment: can you show your client code? how are calling the GetObject operation?  how are you subscribing to GetObject Completed Event

Comment: `e` is just an event arg. I think its not something which gonna return you the data or `Listproducts`.

Comment: @Viru Check Edited post

Comment: The WCF datacontract deserializers won't call your type's constructor and instead use reflection to build the type and populate fields directly.

Comment: I think you have to dig proxy your proxy and check for GetObjectCompletedEventArgs class.....I think this is class which svcutil created automatically when you generated proxy..Post this class code also

Comment: @Viplock e will actually return data here. e has Result property which should contain data....

Comment: one of more thing you have mentioned [DataContract] attribute on ListOfProducts right?

Answer (score 0):

The deserializer [did not call your constructor!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mohamedg/archive/2014/02/05/warning-datacontractserializer-won-t-call-your-constructor.aspx)

Therefore, when you retrieve your `ListOfProducts` on the other end of the service, the `ProductList` property is still `null`.

Comment: There is a suggestion in the linked post. Beyond that, I'd need to know a _lot_ more about what you're doing than would fit in a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn problem here seems to be different. Link says that Constructor wont be called while deserialization but thats not the issue here...After the type is intialized, it should set productList public data member while building the type.

Comment: In the `GetObject` method, I put a breakpoint on `return Listproducts` and it contains the list but on the receiving end `e` contains `null`

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The problem was in the `service_GetObjectCompleted` event. Instead of referencing the `list` like `e.Result`, I needed to reference it like `e.Result.ProductList`. So here is the version that works:

```
void service_GetObjectCompleted(object sender, GetObjectCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.Productlist.Count != 0)  
    {
        PagedCollectionView pagingCollection = new PagedCollectionView(e.Result.Productlist);
        pgrProductGrids.Source = pagingCollection;
        grdProductGrid.ItemsSource = pagingCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: It wasn't until I Updated my service Reference. Since I changed the return type of my Operation Contract, it wasn't updated